Regex $1, $2 data type conversion issue
I'm trying to add YouTube Video Bookmark somewhere.
If my YouTube Video URL is: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxx&t=12:13'
Then it should be convert as format: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxx&t=25s'
Basically I changes the timer format: 12:13 to 733s (12*60 + 13)
I can do it simple way.
But I want to do it in a single line with regex validation like:


let url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxx&t=12:13';

console.log(url.replace(/(\d+)\:(\d+)/g, '$1$2'));

let cUrl = url.replace(/(\d+)\:(\d+)/g, `${Number($1)*60 + Number($2)}s`);
console.log(cUrl);



Browser Console Output:


Can some guide me why it's showing the NaN?
What I'm doing wrong ?

Did you run your own runnable snippet? Because that doesn't even run, it errors out. So until that's fixed: at the very least make sure you actually match the time, e.g. include &?t= at the start.

Yes, it's throwing error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $1 is not defined

Why $1 not define there? regex: url.replace(/(\d+)\:(\d+)/g, '$1$2') is working perfectly

indeed, so fix the snippet to show off the actual problem you're having, because the code you're showing and the error you're showing a picture of don't match (on that note: do not show pictures of text, show the text

It's not defined, because $1 is a special string token that exists during regex string replacement, but you're not using it inside a string, you're using it inside a regular code block that you've put inside a templating string.

I already tried: url.replace(/(\d+)\:(\d+)/g, ${Number('$1')*60 + Number('$2')}s). This is not working also @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

No, of course not: those tokens only work directly in the replacement string. If you want to work with regex capture group data, use a replacer function, not a replacement string. (Give the whole article a read, because learning about everything that you can do with replace is time well spent)

You can use: url.replace(/(\d+):(\d+)$/, function (m, g1, g2) { return Number(g1)*60 + Number(g2) + 's'; });

It'll be helpful to update the answer for others @anubhava

As the comments suggest that you will need to use a use a replacer function instead of a replacement string since you want to convert capture groups to numbers, perform some arithmetic and append some text later.
Following code should work for you:


let url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxx&t=12:13';
let cUrl = url.replace(/(\d+):(\d+)$/, function (m, g1, g2) {
   return Number(g1)*60 + Number(g2) + 's'; });

console.log(cUrl);
//=> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxx&t=733s




One alternative workaround is using eval but use it only when you can trust that original url will not contain any malicious JS code from external users:
let cUrl = eval(url.replace(/(.+=)(\d+):(\d+)$/, '"$1" + ($2*60 + $3) + "s"'));



...but use it only when you can trust that original url will not contain any malicious JS code from external users* - very important point!

